# How to connect MYSQL database from asp file?

Tags: mysql, odbc

I have sample Code like this. Please let me know how to connect Mysql DB from these ASP file. I have installed  MySQLODBC driver 5 on my machine.

```
SQL="select fname,lname from Guest"

set rs=Conn.Execute(SQL)

response.write("<?XML version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>")

response.write("<guestbook>")

while (not rs.EOF)

response.write("<guest>")

response.write("<fname>" & rs("fname") & "</fname>")

response.write("<lname>" & rs("lname") & "</lname>")

response.write("</guest>")

rs.MoveNext()

wend

rs.close()

conn.close()

response.write("</guestbook>")
%>
```